# Match all child items to selected list of parent items in SQL -- Hierarchical data problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, parent-child, hierarchy

I have a SQL Server table that contains hierarchical data of various 'diagram titles' in the form of:

| ID | ParentID | Level | Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10411 | 9925 | 1.1.4 | A |
| 10462 | 10411 | **1.1.4.1** | B |
| 10467 | 10462 | 1.1.4.1.1 | C |
| 10429 | 10411 | 1.1.4.2 | D |
| 10434 | 10429 | **1.1.4.2.1** | E |
| 10435 | 10434 | **1.1.4.2.1.4** | F |
| 10436 | 10435 | 1.1.4.2.1.4.3 | G |
| 10430 | 10429 | **1.1.4.2.3** | H |
| 10431 | 10430 | 1.1.4.2.3.3 | I |
| 10433 | 10431 | 1.1.4.2.3.3.1 | J |
| 10432 | 10433 | 1.1.4.2.3.3.1.1 | K |

I also have a separate table / list of select 'Levels' [bold in the table] that I want to use to tag each associated subtree level as a child of said selected level. Every level that is 'above' the selected list levels get ignored or tag as null.

For instance - using the above example table -- the result I am trying to achieve is:

| ID | ParentID | Level | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10411 | 9925 | 1.1.4 | Null |
| 10462 | 10411 | **1.1.4.1** | 10462 |
| 10467 | 10462 | 1.1.4.1.1 | 10462 |
| 10429 | 10411 | 1.1.4.2 | Null |
| 10434 | 10429 | **1.1.4.2.1** | 10434 |
| 10435 | 10434 | **1.1.4.2.1.4** | 10435 |
| 10436 | 10435 | 1.1.4.2.1.4.3 | 10435 |
| 10430 | 10429 | **1.1.4.2.3** | 10430 |
| 10431 | 10430 | 1.1.4.2.3.3 | 10430 |
| 10433 | 10431 | 1.1.4.2.3.3.1 | 10430 |
| 10432 | 10433 | 1.1.4.2.3.3.1.1 | 10430 |

I have tried playing around with regular old joins on substrings of levels, recursive cte's, and the like but i just haven't been able to produce the desired results.

The biggest problem i faced is the selected list can include levels of any depth greater than 3 & some levels in the list also include their direct child e.g. E & F in the first table.

There's about 2000 or so rows in the data set and they can grow or reduce daily. The selected list doesn't change as often (only gets updated if a new record gets created in the data set and its chosen to be included in the list)

Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this in T-SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
with top_levels as (select ID, Level from MyTable where ID in (1042, 0434,10435,10430))
select ID, ParentID, Level, top_levels.Id as Tag
    from MyTable
         left join top_levels on MyTable.Level like top_levels.Level + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the conditions you have mentioned I have created the sample and dim cte. I hope the below query can satisfy all conditions

```
with sample_
as
(
SELECT 10411 AS ID,9925 AS PARENT_ID,'1.1.4' AS LEVEL,'A' AS TITLE UNION ALL
SELECT 10462,10411,'1.1.4.1','B'UNION ALL
SELECT 10467,10462,'1.1.4.1.1','C'UNION ALL
SELECT 10429,10411,'1.1.4.2','D'UNION ALL
SELECT 10434,10429,'1.1.4.2.1','E'UNION ALL
SELECT 10435,10434,'1.1.4.2.1.4','F'UNION ALL
SELECT 10436,10435,'1.1.4.2.1.4.3','G'UNION ALL
SELECT 10430,10429,'1.1.4.2.3','H'UNION ALL
SELECT 10431,10430,'1.1.4.2.3.3','I'UNION ALL
SELECT 10433,10431,'1.1.4.2.3.3.1','J'UNION ALL
SELECT 10432,10433,'1.1.4.2.3.3.1.1','K'
),
dims as
(
select 10462 as level_to_match_id,'1.1.4.1' as level_to_match union all
select 10434 as level_to_match_id,'1.1.4.2.1' as level_to_match union all
select 10435 as level_to_match_id,'1.1.4.2.1.4' as level_to_match union all
select 10430 as level_to_match_id,'1.1.4.2.3' as level_to_match 
),
cte as
(
select  *, 
        PATINDEX(dims.level_to_match+'%',sample_.LEVEL) as idx,
        LEN(sample_.LEVEL) as len_of_level,
        LEN(dims.level_to_match) as len_of_level_to_match
        from sample_
left join dims on PATINDEX(dims.level_to_match+'%',sample_.LEVEL) <> 0
)
,cte2 as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by len_of_level_to_match  desc) as rn from cte
)
select *,case 
                when level_to_match is null then NULL 
                when len_of_level_to_match = len_of_level then ID 
                when len_of_level_to_match < len_of_level then level_to_match_id
         end as tag
from cte2
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This would basically be a `left join` with filtering . . . except that your "comparison" levels can be in the same hierarchy.  And you want the deepest one.  That suggest `outer apply` instead:

```
select t.*, tparent.*
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) tparent.id as tag
      from t tparent
      where t.level + '.' like tparent.level + '.%' and
            tparent.level in ('1.1.4.1', '1.1.4.2.1', '1.1.4.2.1.4', '1.1.4.2.3')
      order by tparent.level desc    -- get the longest one
     ) tparent;
```

Very important:  This logic adds a `'.'` to the end of the level for the comparison.  This handles the case where you might have more than 9 children in a level, so `1.1` does not match `1.10` for instance.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f65b1635a7dbb1846501aae41e118a25) is a db<>fiddle.